# Assertive code in programming and the definition of it

Tags: algorithm

Is there a simple definition?

What is the nature, so to speak, of "assertive code"?

All the definitions of this I have, by now, found are very vague.

Is there something I can read that is concise and to the point without using a lot of jargon?

I think that the jargon could be a problem in my case. I am quite dumb but I wanna learn it so any help and pointers are welcome.

Comment: Hmm, it's not clear what you mean by "assertive code". Do you have a reference to where it's mentioned (even if that reference is "vague")? There's something called assertions in some languages (eg: C), but you've tagged the question "algorithm" so perhaps you have something algorithm-related in mind.

Comment: @PaulHankin here: "Elixir developers typically prefer to use the map.field syntax and pattern matching instead of the functions in the Map module when working with maps because they lead to an assertive style of programming. " https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html

Comment: An assert is a check performed as your program runs, which causes a crash when it fails. "Assertive code" seems to be a piece of jargon meaning code that tends to crash early when there's a programming error.

Answer (score 2):

When you write "imperative code", you tell the computer what to do.

When you write "declarative code", you tell the computer what to produce.

When you write "assertive code", you tell the computer what you expect to be true.

The phrase "assertive code" isn't nearly as common as the other two, and is used in different ways in practice.  In an common OO language it usually just refers to using `assert` expressions to catch bugs.  In functional programming (the example you provide), it usually refers to pattern matching and destructuring constructs that imply a particular shape for their inputs.  In a language like Prolog, it can refer to a definition of goals that the program must resolve.

Answer (score 0):

An `assert` statement is essentially an `if` statement that will print an error (and, sometimes, stop the program) if the condition is false. If the condition is true, it will do nothing.

Assertions are normally used in software testing. You use them to check that a program behaves in a way that you expect it to. In other words, they will sound an alarm when a program violates an assumption that the programmer wanted to check.

However, there's nothing preventing you from leaving assertions in your production code too. This can sometimes be beneficial, especially in cases where you cannot easily simulate the program with a test - for example because you don't have the real data to test it with.

In such cases you typically want failed assertions just to print a message to a log file. After having your program run for a while, you check the log file and if everything is OK, there should be no messages about failed assertions.